# @types/async "results" type for async.auto(...)

Tags: node.js, async.js, definitelytyped

I use async package and @types/async for getting proper types. Now I have a problem with async.auto() method. The "results" parameter in callback has an unknown type for all keys.

For example:

```
Async.auto({
    create_something: async () => {
        return 'string';
    }
}, (err, results) => {

});
```

The "results.create_something" will have a type unknown, even though the return value of that async function is properly recognized as

```
Promise<string>
```

How do I make Typescript to properly map results types?